# How to find the right file to edit in Magento

Tags: xml, magento, content-management-system, cpanel

I have an already set up Magento website. However I'd like to change few things like menus,... and they do not show in CMS --> Pages (as per many tutorials). It is becoming to difficult to find the right file to edit since they are located in different paths. Is there a technique or a tool to solve this?
P.S: I am not an experienced user of Magento. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check through CMS/Static Blocks

Comment: Yes I did !! Unfortunately the header I wanted to edit is not there

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt template path hints feature which shows exact path of the template file for a particular portion/block of Magento webpage. You can enable them from Magento backend. Goto System > Configuration and change configuration scope to store level using the drop-down in left section above all configuration settings. Then goto Advanced > Developer and then under debug section select Yes for Template path hints drop-down. You can also add your IP in the Allowed IPs textbox under Developer Client Restrictions section so that these template path hints can be visible only to you and not show on frontend for all customers.